# Query to find averge number of students in every batch of each campus

Tags: sql

[image]I have a query which i am  not able to figure out since i am new with sql and i have a project due tomorow to submit

any help will be appreciated

i have a registration table which has the following structure

```
Student_ID int,
Course varchar(15),
Score int,
Semester varchar(15),
Discipline varchar(10),
Campus varchar(15),
Degree varchar(10),
Year int
```

the Registration table has no Primary key it is basically for  developing a date warehouse

so no primary key, and the data in this table is from 4 different campuses of the same university so Student_id is repeated a number of times

The Query is that i need to find average number of students in every batch(YEAR) of each campus

kindly help me if any one can

Comment: "No primary key" is a wrong choice. {campus,student_id,year,semester,course} seems a candidate key to me. And {campus,student_id} and {year,semester} {course} could be stronger dimensions than the separate key elements. (course is harder, because it *could* belong to the {year,semeter} domain, or to the {campus} domain)

Answer (score 0):

i hope this is what is required by you ::

given me some data snap shot for better understanding.

```
select count(1),count(distinct student_id),year,count(distinct student_id)/count(1)   from   registration 
group by year;
```

Comment: Sir dont you think that Campus needs to be the part of Group by clause as well? cause for each semester  of each campus it is required

Comment: sir i have added the image the campus field can have 4 values
those are PESHAWR,ISLAMABAD,LAHORE,KARACHI

Answer (score 0):

```
select year, campus, count(distinct student_id)  from registration
       group by year, campus
```

Comment: Dear sir
in this query can you tell me how is the average being taken, because i think this works right but i am not able to understand that how is the average being calculated

Comment: In this query you group by campus and year  and in each group we select only one student_id per group even if there are many  student_id's in this group [count distinct](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Num_Discipline AS INT

SELECT DISTINCT @Num_Discipline = Count(Discipline)
FROM registration

SELECT Count(student_id) AS nStudents, Count(student_id)/@Num_Discipline AS Avg_Students
FROM registration
GROUP BY Campus, Year
```

`Avg_Students` this is average number of students in each campus in particular year, supposing that campuses have same number of Disciplines.